# Obter atributo href de HTML em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código numa *Razor view*:

```
<div id="HTMLreturned" class="row">

   @Html.Raw(ViewBag.HTMLreturned);

 </div>

<script>

        var nrLinks = 0;

        $(".enlacesMas > a").each(function(){

            nrLinks++;
            var link = "http://www.meu.site" + $(this).attr('href').replace("..","");

            // Agora preciso de guardar todos os link num array ou algo do género


        });


</script>
```

No `controller` coloquei na *ViewBag.HTMLreturned* o resultado desta linha:

```
ViewBag.HTMLreturned = WebClient.client.DownloadString(meuUrl)
```

Como posso correr o código da minha `view` no meu `controller` para puder guardar cada **href numa variável C#**?

#### Obs:

O `html` com o qual o jQuery trabalha é renderizado antes do script ser executado, portanto essas classes são do `html` dentro da `viewbag`

Comment: Como assim, jovem? Explica melhor o que você quer fazer.

Comment: @jbueno acho que ficou mais claro agora

Comment: Depois que executa o each, tu quer armazenar todos os href num array e devolver pra um controller. Isso?

Comment: @Aline, eu não quero ter uma `view`de todo, quero fazer isso tudo no `controller`

Comment: É, não compreendi direito.

Comment: percebi agora que o que queria fazer não vai ser possível, basicamente o que preciso agora transformar esse código jQuery num código c#

Comment: Você pode explicar o que te levou a querer usar código backend no lugar do JQuery? Qual foi seu caso de uso?

Comment: Eu tinha uma string que era um html, e queria extrair informações de la usando uma linguagem como o jQuery, pois já domino algumas tecnicas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegui obter exatamente o mesmo resultado em C# instalando o **CsQueryLatest** com o NuGet, e escrevendo o seguinte código:

```
 string htmlCode = "";
        List<string> links = new List<string>();

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString("https://www.boe.es/buscar/anboe.php?campo%5B0%5D=TIT&dato%5B0%5D=&operador%5B0%5D=and&campo%5B1%5D=ID_DEM&dato%5B1%5D=&operador%5B1%5D=and&campo%5B2%5D=DOC&dato%5B2%5D=&operador%5B2%5D=and&campo%5B3%5D=ID_TIP&dato%5B3%5D=&operador%5B3%5D=and&campo%5B4%5D=GEO&dato%5B4%5D=&operador%5B4%5D=and&campo%5B5%5D=DOC&dato%5B5%5D=&operador%5B6%5D=and&campo%5B6%5D=FPU&dato%5B6%5D%5B0%5D=02%2F01%2F2017&dato%5B6%5D%5B1%5D=02%2F01%2F2017&page_hits=200&sort_field%5B0%5D=FPU&sort_order%5B0%5D=desc&sort_field%5B1%5D=ref&sort_order%5B1%5D=asc&accion=Buscar");
            var query = CQ.Create(htmlCode);
            var rows = query[".enlacesMas a"];
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                var newLink = row.Attributes["href"];
                links.Add(newLink);
                // aqui guardo todos os link numa lista
            }

        }
```